# Issues with a drop down menu

Tags: html, css

I'm using ordered lists to create a menu, and I have run into two issues, the drop down does not align and the hover effect is applied to the drop downs and I don't want that to happen

Here is a JS Fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/HFMR5/

this is my HTML code:

```
<div id="menu">
    <ul id="navigation">
    <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
          <li><a href="">Services</a>
            <ul>
            <li><a href="">Residential</a></li>
            <li><a href="">Buisiness</a></li>
            </ul>
          </li>
          <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
    </ul>
    </div>
```

and this is the CSS for the menu:

```
/*Navigation CSS*/

                #navigation 
                {
                width: 100%;
                float: left;
                margin: 0 0 3em 0;
                padding: 0;
                list-style: none;
                background-color: #f2f2f2;
                border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc; 
                border-top: 1px solid #ccc; 
                box-shadow: 0 8px 6px -6px black;
                }
                #navigation li 
                {
                float: left;
                }
                #navigation li a 
                {
                display: block;
                padding: 8px 15px;
                text-decoration: none;
                font-weight: bold;
                color: #FF6987;
                border-right: 1px solid #ccc; 
                -webkit-transition: all 0.1s ease-in;
                -moz-transition: all 0.1s ease-in;
                -o-transition: all 0.1s ease-in;
                }

                #navigation ul
                {
                font-family: Arial, Verdana;
                font-size: 14px;
                margin: 0;
                padding: 0;
                list-style: none;
                }

                #navigation ul li {
                display: block;
                position: relative;
                float: left;
                }

                #navigation li ul { display: none; }

                #navigation li:hover ul {
                display: block;
                position: absolute;
                }

                #navigation li:hover li {
                float: none;
                font-size: 11px;
                }

                #navigation li:hover a { background: #f2f2f2; }

                #navigation li a:hover 
                {
                color: #FF6987;
                background-color: #f2f2f2; 
                box-shadow: inset 0 8px 6px -6px black;
                }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order for the widths to be the same you need to actually set the width of the sub-menu (Not necessarily static) but if you let it be then it will just expand to the size of the contnent which obviously isn't desired, the CSS changes look like:

```
#navigation li{
    float: left;
    position:relative;
}

#navigation li:hover ul {
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
}
```

The `position: relative` has the sub-menu know to use that element when determining what 100% width is instead of the body tag.

As for the hover effect showing up on sub-menu items all that you need to do is be more specific in your selector. The space you are using signifies that you will select and descendant of `#navigation` that is a `li` element. That includes the submenus. If you use a selector like the `>` which signifies a direct child then you will be able to bre more specific in targeting only top level menu items. CSS looks something like:

```
#navigation > li > a:hover{
    color: #FF6987;
    background-color: #f2f2f2; 
    box-shadow: inset 0 8px 6px -6px black;
}
```

A good reference for CSS selectors: http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp

Comment: So I would use the same system if I wanted to just apply CSS to the child items?

Comment: right, I'd give a class to the submenu `UL` and select the `li` children of that to give the style